# ASP.NET MVC 4 RemoteAttribute action name

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, attributes, asp.net-mvc-routing

Is it possible to get action name of `System.Web.Mvc.RemoteAttribute object`. (Initialized at constructor stage)

`GetUrl()` method and `RouteData` property are protected. Are there any hints?

Answer (score 0):

With reflection you can get protected properties.
The better solution I think is to create a new attribute class derived from RemoteAttribute and add some public methods/properties which return the Url and RouteData. For example:

```
public class MyRemoteAttribute: System.Web.Mvc.RemoteAttribute
{
  public string GetUrlPublic()
  {
    return this.GetUrl();
  }
  public RouteValueDictionary GetRouteData()
  {
    return this.RouteData;
  }
}
```

Comment: Reflection is too complicated for such due task. Derived class is the same. Much easier to create own Attribute with just needed functionality.